# why doesn't awk seem to work on splitting into fields based on alternative involving "."?

Tags: awk

It is OK to awk split on `.`:

```
>printf foo.bar | awk '{split($0, a, "."); print a[1]}'
foo
```

It is OK to awk split on an alternative:

```
>printf foo.bar | awk '{split($0, a, "b|a"); print a[1]}'
foo.
```

Then why is it not OK to split on an anternative involving `.`:

```
>printf foo.bar | awk '{split($0, a, ".|a"); print a[1]}'
```

(nothing printed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape that period and I think you'll be golden:

```
 printf foo.bar | awk '{split($0, a, "\\.|a"); print a[1]}'
```

Comment: Correct - but why wasn't even a single escape needed previously, without alternation?

Answer (score 0):

JNevill showed how to get it working. But to answer your question of why the escape is needed in one case but not the other, we can find the answer in the awk manual in the summary of "how fields are split, based on the value of FS." (And the same rules apply to the *fieldsep* given to the `split` command.)

The bottom line is that when FS is a single character it is not treated as a regular expression but otherwise it is.

Hence `split($0, a, ".")` works as we hope, taking `.` to literally be `.`, but `split($0, a, ".|a")` takes `.|a` to be a regexp where `.` has a special meaning, setting the separator to be *any character*, and with that the necessity to add the backslashes to have the `.` treated literally.

> **FS == " "**
>   Fields are separated by runs of whitespace. Leading and trailing whitespace are ignored. This is the default.
>
> **FS == any single character**
>       Fields are separated by each occurrence of the character. Multiple successive occurrences delimit empty fields, as do leading and
>   trailing occurrences.
>
> **FS == regexp**
>       Fields are separated by occurrences of characters that match regexp. Leading and trailing matches of regexp delimit empty fields.

You can see the despite the empty result `.|a` is really doing something, dividing the line into eight empty fields --- same as a line like `,,,,,,,` would do with `FS` set to `,`.

```
$ printf foo.bar | awk '{split($0, a, ".|a"); for (i in a) print i ": " a[i]; }'
4: 
5: 
6: 
7: 
8: 
1: 
2: 
3:
```